# Greensock :TweenMax Restarting multiple timeline

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am using green sock animation library to do some animation stuff. following is my code.

**Tweenmax code:**

```
var slide4 = (function() {
  function animate() {
    var timelineFour = new TimelineLite();
    timelineFour.to("#brand-welcome-para", 1, {
        'margin-top': 0,
        'opacity': 1,
        'delay': 1
      })
      .to("#slide-1-creator-icon", 0.6, {
        'top': 300,
        'left': 45,
        'width': 155,
        'height': 155,
        ease: Elastic.easeOut
      })
      .to("#avatar-one", 0.6, {
        'left': 27,
        rotation: '-360'
      })
      .to("#avatar-two", 0.6, {
        'left': 100,
        rotation: '-360'
      })
      .to("#avatar-four", 0.6, {
        'left': '-50',
        rotation: '360'
      })
      .to("#cover-one", 1, {
        width: 0,
        ease: Linear.easeNone
      }, 'firstLoop')

    .to("#slide-1-tandem-icon", 0.6, {
        'top': 300,
        'width': 155,
        'height': 155,
        ease: Elastic.easeOut
      })
      .to("#cover-one-two", 1, {
        width: 0,
        ease: Linear.easeNone
      })

    .to("#slide-1-brand-icon", 0.6, {
        'top': 300,
        'right': 45,
        'width': 155,
        'height': 155,
        ease: Elastic.easeOut
      })
      .to("#cover-two", 2, {
        width: 0,
        ease: Linear.easeNone
      });

    var timelineChild = new TimelineMax({
      repeat: -1,
      onComplete: complete,
      delay: 4
    });
    timelineChild.to("#rotator", 1, {
        rotation: -90,
        delay: 1
      }, 'firstLoop')
      .to("#avatar-one", 1, {
        rotation: -270,
        delay: 1
      }, 'firstLoop')
      .to("#avatar-two", 1, {
        rotation: -270,
        delay: 1
      }, 'firstLoop')
      .to("#avatar-three", 1, {
        rotation: -270,
        delay: 1
      }, 'firstLoop')
      .to("#avatar-four", 1, {
        rotation: -270,
        delay: 1
      }, 'firstLoop')

    .to("#rotator", 1, {
        rotation: -180,
        delay: 1
      }, 'secondLoop')
      .to("#avatar-one", 1, {
        rotation: -180,
        delay: 1
      }, 'secondLoop')
      .to("#avatar-two", 1, {
        rotation: -180,
        delay: 1
      }, 'secondLoop')
      .to("#avatar-three", 1, {
        rotation: -180,
        delay: 1
      }, 'secondLoop')
      .to("#avatar-four", 1, {
        rotation: -180,
        delay: 1
      }, 'secondLoop')

    .to("#rotator", 1, {
        rotation: -270,
        delay: 1
      }, 'thirdLoop')
      .to("#avatar-one", 1, {
        rotation: -90,
        delay: 1
      }, 'thirdLoop')
      .to("#avatar-two", 1, {
        rotation: -90,
        delay: 1
      }, 'thirdLoop')
      .to("#avatar-three", 1, {
        rotation: -90,
        delay: 1
      }, 'thirdLoop')
      .to("#avatar-four", 1, {
        rotation: -90,
        delay: 1
      }, 'thirdLoop')

    .to("#rotator", 1, {
        rotation: -360,
        delay: 1
      }, 'fourthLoop')
      .to("#avatar-one", 1, {
        rotation: 0,
        delay: 1
      }, 'fourthLoop')
      .to("#avatar-two", 1, {
        rotation: 0,
        delay: 1
      }, 'fourthLoop')
      .to("#avatar-three", 1, {
        rotation: 0,
        delay: 1
      }, 'fourthLoop')
      .to("#avatar-four", 1, {
        rotation: 0,
        delay: 1
      }, 'fourthLoop');

    function complete(timelineChild) {
      timelineChild.restart(); // 0 sets the playhead at the end of the animation
    }
  }

  function restart() {
    timelineFour.restart();
  }

  function getTimeline() {
    return timelineFour;
  }

  return {
    animate: animate,
    restart: restart,
    timeline: getTimeline
  }

})();
```

I want to restart this timeline on a button click from HTML.

Comment: can you put together a fiddle please? by looking at your code, it is not very apparent as to what exactly is _currently_ happening. also, show us the code you have tried for button clicking and trying to restart the timeline on it.

Comment: @TahirAhmed : Its very difficult to put all working code together. as the view is getting rendered using angular rout. Precisely I just want to know that how can I restart two timelines at one time using one function that's it.

Comment: perhaps simple calls to `timelineFour.restart();` & `timelineChild.restart();` would do inside your button click handler. shooting in the dark here because I cannot comprehend the whole thing. you seem to already know this solution though, I think.

Comment: @TahirAhmed: It gives an Error :  "Cannot read property 'restart' of undefined"

Comment: scope issues for sure. your `animate` function is the one carrying the reference to `timelineFour` and `timelineChild` i.e. the `var` declarations line and you are trying to access them outside of it hence `undefined`. just take these `var` lines out of the scope of `animate` function and put them as first 2 lines within your `slide` closure function and that should do it.

Comment: @TahirAhmed I did what you suggested, the error message is gone now. but animation did not restarted yet. ;(

Comment: it is way too difficult to debug for me to be honest. try creating a reduced test case and share it with me.

Comment: @TahirAhmed :  No problem buddy, I have figured out a work around, but thanks for your incessant support and help. I am using `this.timelineFour` instead of var timelineFour, by which I am able to access timelineFour like `slide4.timelineFour.restart();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.restart()` function as described in their documentations:

https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/restart/

```
//restarts, not including any delay that was defined
myAnimation.restart();

//restarts, including any delay, and doesn't suppress events during the initial move back to time:0
myAnimation.restart(true, false);
```